# Number of elements less than given number in binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write the following method for a lab assignment but have become very stuck on it. We are working with binary search tree's and they have asked for this method `"int sizeBelow(T high) returns the number of elements in the tree that are strictly less than high"` If someone could help me figure out how to write this it would be really appreciated! Been stuck on this for way too long

```
package week11;

import java.util.Scanner;

import static week11.LinkedBST.Direction.*;

/**
 *  A binary tree implementation using links. We assume that the tree
 *  is not to store 'null' elements. In particular if the root node
 *  *is* null then the tree is empty. This can only occur if a tree
 *  is initially constructed with no arguments, or if we remove the
 *  only element from a tree.
 *
 *  @author Michael Albert, Iain Hewson
 */
public class LinkedBST<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    /** The element held at the root of this tree. */
    private T root;

    /** The left subtree of this tree. */
    private LinkedBST<T> left;

    /** The right subtree of this tree. */
    private LinkedBST<T> right;

    /**
     *  Creates a BST with the given value.
     *
     * @param value to store at the root of this LinkedBST.
     */
    public LinkedBST(T value) {
        root = value;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    /** 
     *  Creates a new empty BST.
     */
    public LinkedBST() {
        this(null);
    }

    /**
     *  Adds an element to this BST if it isn't already there.
     *
     * @param element an element to be added.
     */
    public void add(T element) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = element;
        }
        int comparison = root.compareTo(element);
        if (comparison > 0) {
            if (left == null) {
                left = new LinkedBST<T>(element);
            } else {
                left.add(element);
            }
        } else if (comparison < 0) {
            if (right == null) {
                right = new LinkedBST<T>(element);
            } else {
                right.add(element);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Returns the height of this tree.
     *
     * @return the height of this tree.
     */
    public int height() {
        int leftH = 0, rightH = 0;
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (right != null) {
            rightH = 1 + right.height();
        }
        if (left != null) {
            leftH = 1 + left.height();
        }
        return Math.max(leftH, rightH);
    }

    /**
     *  Searches for the given target within this tree.
     *
     * @param target 
     * @return true if target is found, otherwise false.
     */
    public boolean search(T target) {
        boolean lefth = false, righth = false;
        if (root == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int comparison = root.compareTo(target);
        if (comparison == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (comparison > 0) {
            if (left != null) {
                lefth = left.search(target);
            }
            return lefth;
        }
        if (comparison < 0) {
            if (right != null) {
                righth = right.search(target);
            }
            return righth;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns the size of this BST.
     *
     * @return the size of this BST.
     */
    public int size() {
        int lefth = 0, righth = 0;
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (right != null) {
            righth = right.size();
        }
        if (left != null) {
            lefth = left.size();
        }
        return 1 + lefth + righth;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns how many elements are greater than or equal to the
     *  parameter <code>low</code>.
     *
     * @param low the lower bound to use when counting elements.
     * @return how many elements are greater than or equal to the
     *         parameter <code>low</code>.
     */
    public int sizeAbove(T low) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns how many elements are less than the parameter
     *  <code>high</code>.
     *
     * @param high the element to compare when counting elements.
     * @return how many elements are less than the parameter
     *         <code>high</code>.
     */
    public int sizeBelow(T high) {
        // implement this for part 2
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns how many elements are greater than or equal to the
     *  parameter <code>low</code> and less than the parameter
     *  <code>high</code>.
     *
     * @param low the lower bound to use when counting elements.
     * @param high the upper bound to use when counting elements.
     * @return how many elements are between low (inclusive) and
     *         high (exclusive).
     */
    public int sizeBetween(T low, T high) {
        // implement this for part 2
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     *  Removes the given element from this tree if it is present.
     *
     * @param element the element to remove.
     */
    public void remove(T element) {
        // implement this method from the lectures if you
        // want to do the extension exercises
    }

    /** The direction used when creating a representation of this tree. */
    enum Direction {LEFT, RIGHT, NO};

    /**
     *  Recursively generates a representation of this tree.
     *
     * @param curr the current line being generated.
     * @param dir the direction of the last link followed.
     * @param result the representation generated so far.
     * @return a representation of this tree.
     */
    public StringBuilder str(String curr, Direction dir, StringBuilder result) {
        if(right != null) {
            right.str(curr + (dir == LEFT ? "│  " : "   "), RIGHT, result);
        }
        if (root != null) {
            result.append(curr + (dir == RIGHT ? "┌─ " :
                                  dir == LEFT ? "└─ " : "  ") + root + "\n");
        }
        if(left != null) {
            left.str(curr +  (dir == RIGHT ? "│  " : "   "), LEFT, result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return str("", NO, new StringBuilder()).toString();
    }

    /**
     *  Entry point of program (used for testing).
     *  Valid commands are:
     *  <pre>
     *  a (add) item(s)             - calls add with each item
     *  f (find) item               - calls search with item
     *  p (print)                   - calls toString
     *  h (height)                  - calls height
     *  s (size)                    - calls size
     *  sa (sizeabove) low          - calls sizeAbove(low)
     *  sb (sizebelow) high         - calls sizeBelow(high)
     *  si (sizeinbetween) low high - calls sizeBetween(low,high)
     *  </pre>
     *  Return values of methods are printed to stdout.
     *
     * @param args command line arguments are not used.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedBST<String> tree = new LinkedBST<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner line = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
            if (line.hasNext()) {
                String command = line.next();
                switch (command) {
                    case "a": case "add":
                        while (line.hasNext()) {
                            tree.add(line.next());
                        }
                        break;
                    case "f": case "find":
                        if (line.hasNext()) {
                            System.out.println(tree.search(line.next()));
                        }
                        break;
                    case "p": case "print":
                        System.out.print(tree);
                        break;
                    case "h": case "height":
                        System.out.println(tree.height());
                        break;
                    case "s": case "size":
                        System.out.println(tree.size());
                        break;
                    case "sa": case "sizeabove":
                        if (line.hasNext()) {
                            String low = line.next();
                            System.out.println(tree.sizeAbove(low));
                        }
                        break;
                    case "sb": case "sizebelow":
                        if (line.hasNext()) {
  package week11;

import java.util.Scanner;

import static week11.LinkedBST.Direction.*;

/**
 *  A binary tree implementation using links. We assume that the tree
 *  is not to store 'null' elements. In particular if the root node
 *  *is* null then the tree is empty. This can only occur if a tree
 *  is initially constructed with no arguments, or if we remove the
 *  only element from a tree.
 *
 *  @author Michael Albert, Iain Hewson
 */
public class LinkedBST<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    /** The element held at the root of this tree. */
    private T root;

    /** The left subtree of this tree. */
    private LinkedBST<T> left;

    /** The right subtree of this tree. */
    private LinkedBST<T> right;

    /**
     *  Creates a BST with the given value.
     *
     * @param value to store at the root of this LinkedBST.
     */
    public LinkedBST(T value) {
        root = value;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    /** 
     *  Creates a new empty BST.
     */
    public LinkedBST() {
        this(null);
    }

    /**
     *  Adds an element to this BST if it isn't already there.
     *
     * @param element an element to be added.
     */
    public void add(T element) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = element;
        }
        int comparison = root.compareTo(element);
        if (comparison > 0) {
            if (left == null) {
                left = new LinkedBST<T>(element);
            } else {
                left.add(element);
            }
        } else if (comparison < 0) {
            if (right == null) {
                right = new LinkedBST<T>(element);
            } else {
                right.add(element);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Returns the height of this tree.
     *
     * @return the height of this tree.
     */
    public int height() {
        int leftH = 0, rightH = 0;
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (right != null) {
            rightH = 1 + right.height();
        }
        if (left != null) {
            leftH = 1 + left.height();
        }
        return Math.max(leftH, rightH);
    }

    /**
     *  Searches for the given target within this tree.
     *
     * @param target 
     * @return true if target is found, otherwise false.
     */
    public boolean search(T target) {
        boolean lefth = false, righth = false;
        if (root == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int comparison = root.compareTo(target);
        if (comparison == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (comparison > 0) {
            if (left != null) {
                lefth = left.search(target);
            }
            return lefth;
        }
        if (comparison < 0) {
            if (right != null) {
                righth = right.search(target);
            }
            return righth;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns the size of this BST.
     *
     * @return the size of this BST.
     */
    public int size() {
        int lefth = 0, righth = 0;
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (right != null) {
            righth = right.size();
        }
        if (left != null) {
            lefth = left.size();
        }
        return 1 + lefth + righth;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns how many elements are greater than or equal to the
     *  parameter <code>low</code>.
     *
     * @param low the lower bound to use when counting elements.
     * @return how many elements are greater than or equal to the
     *         parameter <code>low</code>.
     */
    public int sizeAbove(T low) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns how many elements are less than the parameter
     *  <code>high</code>.
     *
     * @param high the element to compare when counting elements.
     * @return how many elements are less than the parameter
     *         <code>high</code>.
     */
    public int sizeBelow(T high) {
        // implement this for part 2
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns how many elements are greater than or equal to the
     *  parameter <code>low</code> and less than the parameter
     *  <code>high</code>.
     *
     * @param low the lower bound to use when counting elements.
     * @param high the upper bound to use when counting elements.
     * @return how many elements are between low (inclusive) and
     *         high (exclusive).
     */
    public int sizeBetween(T low, T high) {
        // implement this for part 2
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     *  Removes the given element from this tree if it is present.
     *
     * @param element the element to remove.
     */
    public void remove(T element) {
        // implement this method from the lectures if you
        // want to do the extension exercises
    }

    /** The direction used when creating a representation of this tree. */
    enum Direction {LEFT, RIGHT, NO};

    /**
     *  Recursively generates a representation of this tree.
     *
     * @param curr the current line being generated.
     * @param dir the direction of the last link followed.
     * @param result the representation generated so far.
     * @return a representation of this tree.
     */
    public StringBuilder str(String curr, Direction dir, StringBuilder result) {
        if(right != null) {
            right.str(curr + (dir == LEFT ? "│  " : "   "), RIGHT, result);
        }
        if (root != null) {
            result.append(curr + (dir == RIGHT ? "┌─ " :
                                  dir == LEFT ? "└─ " : "  ") + root + "\n");
        }
        if(left != null) {
            left.str(curr +  (dir == RIGHT ? "│  " : "   "), LEFT, result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return str("", NO, new StringBuilder()).toString();
    }

    /**
     *  Entry point of program (used for testing).
     *  Valid commands are:
     *  <pre>
     *  a (add) item(s)             - calls add with each item
     *  f (find) item               - calls search with item
     *  p (print)                   - calls toString
     *  h (height)                  - calls height
     *  s (size)                    - calls size
     *  sa (sizeabove) low          - calls sizeAbove(low)
     *  sb (sizebelow) high         - calls sizeBelow(high)
     *  si (sizeinbetween) low high - calls sizeBetween(low,high)
     *  </pre>
     *  Return values of methods are printed to stdout.
     *
     * @param args command line arguments are not used.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedBST<String> tree = new LinkedBST<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner line = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
            if (line.hasNext()) {
                String command = line.next();
                switch (command) {
                    case "a": case "add":
                        while (line.hasNext()) {
                            tree.add(line.next());
                        }
                        break;
                    case "f": case "find":
                        if (line.hasNext()) {
                            System.out.println(tree.search(line.next()));
                        }
                        break;
                    case "p": case "print":
                        System.out.print(tree);
                        break;
                    case "h": case "height":
                        System.out.println(tree.height());
                        break;
                    case "s": case "size":
                        System.out.println(tree.size());
                        break;
                    case "sa": case "sizeabove":
                        if (line.hasNext()) {
                            String low = line.next();
                            System.out.println(tree.sizeAbove(low));
                        }
                        break;
                    case "sb": case "sizebelow":
                        if (line.hasNext()) {
                            System.out.println(tree.sizeBelow(line.next()));
                        }
                        break;
                    case "si": case "sizeinbetween":
                        if (line.hasNext()) {
                            String low = line.next();
                            if (line.hasNext()) {
                                System.out.println(tree.sizeBetween
                                                   (low, line.next()));
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.err.println("Unknown command: " + command);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
                          System.out.println(tree.sizeBelow(line.next()));
                        }
                        break;
                    case "si": case "sizeinbetween":
                        if (line.hasNext()) {
                            String low = line.next();
                            if (line.hasNext()) {
                                System.out.println(tree.sizeBetween
                                                   (low, line.next()));
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.err.println("Unknown command: " + command);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/3141234

Comment: Not asking you to, just looking for help as I have been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Read the post I linked, specifically the points under the "Asking about homework" heading

Comment: I think with "binary tree" you mean "binary search tree"? If so, use the defintion: if a `Node` has value `x`, then its left subtree has only `Node`s with values `<= x`, while its right subtree has only `Node`s with values `> x`.

Comment: Please, it's very important to post only the necessary pieces of code. Posting all your code just made the task harder to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is homework I will try to point you in the right direction rather than do it for you. The task at hand is better solved with recursion and when it comes to binary trees, there are several different types of traversals that can be done recursively.

- In-order traversal (LVR)
- Reverse order traversal (RVL)
- Preorder traversal (VLR)
- Postorder traversal (LRV)

I would perform an In-order traversal and increment accordingly if we find any value below `high`.

Hint:

you'll need to create an `inOrder` method which takes an argument of the `root` and an argument of `T high` and recursively traverse down the tree checking if the current node value is less that `high`.

```
public int sizeBelow(T high) {
    // return inOrder(root,high);
}

private int inOrder(type current, type high){
       // check if ANY of root or high are null (if yes return 0)
       // recursively go down the tree comparing current against high
       // if current is less than high then return 1 + inOrder(...,high)
       // all other conditions should return 0.
}
```

Ensure you read on [Tree Traversals (Inorder, Preorder and Postorder)](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/). When you click on this link ensure you select the `JAVA` tab because by default the examples are shown in `C`.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been working away at it and think I am close. https://paste.ofcode.org/RSrcdVvP6iZAivbUdKFWsg I am having a problem now which is that I get a bad operand types error when I compare left > low? Any ideas why

Comment: @eZ_Harry As per the link you've posted you'll need to utilise the `compareTo` method rather than the operator `>`. i.e `if (left.root.compareTo(low) > 0)` and `if (right.root.compareTo(low) > 0)`, Also, if the solution has helped, don't forget to mark as accepted ^^.